# Drools Fusion: measure performance

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine, complex-event-processing, drools-fusion

I want to measure the performance of drools based on the number on rules and the complexity of the rules. I therefore need to measure the time it takes to handle the events. I want to write a simple test like this:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    insertHeartRate(150, 0, macAddress);
    ksession.fireAllRules();
}
long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("Running time: " + (stop - start));
```

The problem I'm facing is that this doesn't work since you can insert a much as
events you want and drools will handle them later. So the timing of this
part is always less then a second obviously. So my question is how can I 
call `long stop = System.currentTimeMillis()` after all the events are handled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fireAllRules` returns after everything has happened. So the code you have posted will indeed measure the elapsed time for inserting those events, and for firing all triggered rules.

If your rules start any timers which will execute later: that's another matter. Also, you are addressing Fusion: those events will not arrive according to a tight loop, and timestamps and window:time and temporal operators: nothing will work as anticipated in your rules.

If there are no temporal operators, or window:time, you can measure the time it takes to insert facts first, and measure the duration of fireAllRules.

All is highly dependent on Java's JIT, GC behaviour and some details of your CPU...

**Edit** After looking at your code I can add another recommendation. Make sure that you have a sequential sequence of events bracketing insertions and rule executions. Either run everything - inserts and fireAllRules, once or repeatedly - in one thread and measure the time before and after. Or, run fireUntilHalt in one thread, measure the time and insert in another thread. Now, to see when everything has died down after the last insert, you'll have to construct something to catch that moment. One way would be to insert some special fact, to trigger a rule with very low salience, and measure the end time in its consequence.

Comment: I am using window:time. I did the same with Esper (another cep engine) and there this loop does work even though I also use win:time. One solution that came to mind is insert an event after all the others that fires a specific rule and do `long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();` when this rule fires. But I rather avoid this, is there another way?

Comment: There shouldn't be anything happening after the return from fireAllRules.

Comment: Oke but how should I measure the execution time when there are rules with window:time? When do fireAllRules it takes a long time until all the events are processed. This is what I want to measure. How can I achieve this?

Comment: When you insert events in drools and do fireallrules there must be some other thread that handles these events? Can't you measure when this thread has finished?

Comment: The (one) thread inserting events and calling fireAllRules is all you need. Handling events beyond that isn't Drools any more.

Comment: Oke then I want to measure the handeling of events after that how it takes, how do I do that?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Why can't the consequences of your rules settle the matter?

Comment: When I measure the performance with Esper and I insert 1000 events, it takes 2500 milliseconds to handle all of them. When I do this with Drools Fusion and follow your suggestion for measuring (so my original code in my question) it only takes 95 milliseconds which is not possible since drools is slower than Esper. Beside rules are still being fired after I print my `Running time` which indicate that Drools is not finished handeling the events. I only use window.time and no timers so this shouldn't be the problem why Drools fires events.

Comment: Per javadoc, an unlimited fireAllRules does not return until all pending activations have been elaborated. If you can compose a demo substantiating your claim (i.e., rules still firing after the last return), I can pursue the matter by registering a bug.  Edit the necessary rule(s) and the Java app into your question, and I'll take it from there.

Comment: Thanks! Here is a dropbox link were you can download my source code. The code can be run from the main class in the test package: https://www.dropbox.com/s/at6clhqz1y2k0jb/DroolsSpeedTest.zip?dl=0

Comment: The code is a tangle. You create a session and start a thread running fireUntilHalt, then you insert facts and call fireAllRules in another thread, and that's where you measure time, resulting in 225 ms. But rules will fire asynchronously in the thread running fireUntilHalt - so all output from RHS code comes after the display of 225. Simple comment out the start of the thread, and then fireAllRules will control rule execution, and the time will be 656 ms, printed after all the messages.  - I've added some good advice to my answer.

Comment: Yes indeed that was the problem. Thank you!  One last question, you said: "Also, you are addressing Fusion: those events will not arrive according to a tight loop". Can I make that those events do arrive according to a tight loop?

Comment: If (as typical for Fusion) events arrive in real time, measuring performance is virtually impossible - you cannot measure many short activities due to the system clock granularity, at least not with sufficient accuracy. But if you feed the events in a tight loop, you'll have to set time stamps explicitly and advance a pseudo-timer accordingly, running everything in time lapse.